# To what point is a warforged half-heal rounded?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warforged

Eberron campaign setting page 23 says warforged healing is halved, but it does not specify if it's rounded up or down, so I don't know if lesser vigor, for example, would heal 1 or 0 damage per turn.

What is the rule for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actual healing is halved, rounded down (per the 'always round down unless otherwise stated' general rule).

Fast healing is an ability that [constructs can benefit fully from](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#constructType):

> Cannot heal damage on their own, but often can be repaired by exposing them to a certain kind of effect (see the creature’s description for details) or through the use of the Craft Construct feat. **A construct with the fast healing special quality still benefits from that quality.**

(emphasis mine) So presumably living constructs can as well, and so should heal the full amount from spells that grant fast healing.

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51346/can-the-heal-spell-and-other-positive-energy-effects-work-on-constructs might be useful as a reference. Warforged are an odd exception to these rules.

Comment: It's worth noting that most things that would get rounded down to 0 (such as damage) have a minimum of 1. It's up to your DM, but without a quote from a book for a ruling, I'd say they either get the full benefit of Fast Healing 1 (as it's a minimum of 1) or get the benefit Fast Healing 1 every other round (as that would be at half the speed of Fast Healing 1) with the first point healing occurring on the 2nd round after it goes into effect.